# How to clear all items in a ListBox, when we select other item in a DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, listbox, pageload

I have a Listbox named `listbox1`, a `show` button and a DropDownList control in my design page.

- DropDownList contains a list of *group types*.
- *OnClick* method of `show` button will fetch data based on a grouptype from DB and populate in Listbox1.

But if I select other item in DropDownList, the items in listbox are equal to previous selection. I want to clear the items before selecting another item and clicking on `show` button.

How to achieve that?

Comment: `Listbox1.Items.Clear();` is what you need. Next time please do a little bit of search in google before posting in SO.

Comment: Suprabhat biswal i know to clear listbox.But i just need to know how to clear if value gets changed in dropdownlistbox.I mean the condition under which we clear

Comment: You mean if your DropDownList content gets changed both by length or text then at that point you want to clear your Listbox. Hope i understood your problem.

Comment: Let us consider there are 3 items in dropdownlist-red,blue and orange.I have selected red , clicked show button  and data is populated in listbox.Now upon selection of other options i.e.,blue or orange ,listbox must clear the contents.

Comment: @user3837883 be more clear in your examples please. You need clearing your listbox, but SuprabhatBiswal said it to you, how to do that, but you don't want that. Explain your example or give more clear example

Comment: @Khazratbek i want to clear the listbox upon change in selection of item in dropdownlistbox.

Comment: Add an OnSelectedIndexChanged event, if any dropdownlist items gets changed this event fires up and here you can clear the listbox, but this will trigger a postback event, so it's better use client side script to perform such action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGroupTypes" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ClearListBox" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

Your code behind:

```
protected void ClearListBox(object sender, EventArgs e){
    ListBox1.Items.Clear();
}
```

Your show button OnClick method:

```
protected void ShowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    BindYourListBoxAsYouNeed();
}
```

When you will select any other item, your ListBox will be cleared. And when you will click on Show button, you have to populate your ListBox items again.

Is this what you need?

Comment: NO. I want to know the condition upon change in selection of red to blue in dropdown.I know clearing items in listbox. i am not that dumb to ask it here.Currently my selection is red upon change in selection to blue the listbox should clear.

Comment: @user3837883 I can't understand you. I can't understand what you need. Give a clear example